# Exclude TWO variables from SQL query

Tags: sql, where-clause

I know this is going to be answered in all of two seconds, but I can't find it anywhere online.  I need to omit two things from my query...

1. Where display=no
2. Where verified=null

I don't want their information showing up if they've set their display to "no" or they haven't been verified (I put in a "yes" when they've been verified")

As you can see, I only included those with display='yes'.  How do I get the other part?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE display='yes'"
```

Do I just do this?

```
SELECT * FROM $table WHERE display='yes' AND verified='yes'"
```

Comment: The question could be better worded.  In the first part you are asking about =no and =null, while in the things you tried, you are using yes.  Are you attempting to say that the values for the columns are  'yes', 'no' or NULL? or perhaps just 'yes' or 'no'?  That sort of clarification would go a long way toward getting exactly the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

```
WHERE display<>'no' AND verified IS NOT NULL
```

verified = NULL will never match, as by definition the result is NULL which is in effect a nomatch.  Testing NULL for equality really ought to be a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments everyone.  This is what I ended up going with:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE display='yes' AND verified='yes'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result) {

    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
```

Worked like a charm!  Excluding those who said "yes" to "please display my info" and "yes" to those that had been verified.  Sorry for the confusion in my initial question!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use the `AND` keyword in the `WHERE` clause.  You should also give it a try, and let us know if there are any issues.

Answer (score -1):

Try it out with 'LIKE':

```
SELECT * FROM $TABLE WHERE DISPLAY LIKE 'yes' AND VERIFIED LIKE 'yes'
```

Comment: It is good practice to compare the "Strings" with 'LIKE' operator.

Comment: Do you have a source for that statement?

Comment: Why?  If you want an equals comparison, and not a wildcard string match, why is it good practice to use LIKE?

Comment: a like operator without a wild card(%) is an equals operator.

Comment: this is not a like statement. Use LIKE for in-string matching, like "contains". E.g `LIKE '%erifie%'` Not when you have an exact value.